# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+ (android studio)

Tags: android-studio

Despues de genera un proyecto de pruebas en android studio, llega un momento en el que obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues de hacer click en el mensaje, este inicia la instalacion, pero resulta que sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

```
android studio 1.5.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El caso fue de que como el mansaje decia:

```
Failed to resolved com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15+
```

Y justo debajo un link que iniciaba una instalacion creia que se estaba instalando dicha version.

Despues de indagar puede ver que la que realmente se instalo fue la revision `23.1.1` de la misma.

build.gradle (module: app)

./app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.temp.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15+'
}
```

Solucion donde aparece la linea que es creada automaticamente del fichero mostrado anteriormente:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15+'
```

Sustituir el numero `15+` que es señala la revision que empleara por el de la `revision 23.1.1` o la que se descargase o que la que tengas instalada quedando algo asi:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Si como yo no tienes ni idea de cual se descargo puedes mirarlo abriendo el `SDK Manager` >> en la pestaña `SDK Tools` y buscarlo por ahi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]